# top -10 unique dictionary keys to be found on the basis of value

Tags: python, dictionary, hashmap

Need to find out the top-10 dictionary key's  on the basis of value.... value is a tuple of two fields..

```
{ Key : (value1, value2) }
```

So first, we have to find the list of key's on the basis of top 10 value1's and then we have to find the list of key's on the basis of top 10 value2's.

And then we have to find the set of list1 and list2, and return the list...

How can we do this in pythonic way...

Or I should i write the complete logic, to do this stuff...

I wrote one solution:
where the dictionary is a key:value pair.....

```
dict(sorted(dict_mapping.iteritems(), key=lambda dict_mapping:dict_mapping[1]) [0:10]).keys()
```

Please help..

Comment: try to use 1 or 2 character length parameters in lambda, it would make it more readable.

Comment: Can you clarify "And then we have to find the set of list1 and list2, and return the list..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dictionary values are tuples, python's sorted() will do a lexicographical sorting. This means, value1 will be used to sort and value2 will be used for tie-breaking.

```
sorted(a.keys(), key=a.get)[:10]
```

This should result in the top 10 keys that are sorted by values instead of keys in the dictionary.

Comment: Hi, I found your solution worth it.. As other solutions were not giving me the correct outputs. but is it possible to return the sorted sequence either on value1 only or value2 only.... both should not be used...... I have converted first into list, and then used sorted function. tough.... but is there any implementation with dict only... not to use list memory again....

Answer (score 1):

```
sorted(data.keys(), key=lambda x: data[x][1])[:10]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {'key1': ('value1', 'value2'), 'key2': ('value3', 'value4')}

tmp = [sorted(data.keys(), key=lambda x: data[x][i])[:10] for i in (0, 1)]
result = set(tmp[0]+tmp[1])
```